# Computing the area of the intersection of a sphere with a cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Find the area $A$ of the surface $S$. $S$ is the part of the sphere 
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8$ that lies inside the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$.

I know I have to use the double integral surface area formula but I don't know how to set up the integral.

Thanks

Comment: Something about $2z^2=8$ and something about polar coordinates...

Comment: It is extremely helpful to sketch out the region first.

Comment: Parametrize the surface by spherical coordinates, and the constraint $x^2+y^2\leq z^2$ gives you the bounds of each variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sperical coordinates:
$$x=\sqrt{8} \cos s \cos t,$$
$$y=\sqrt{8} \cos s \sin t,$$
$$z=\sqrt{8} \sin s,$$
The bounds for $t$ is $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. To determine the bounds for $s$, note that the surface lies inside the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$, we have $z^2\geq x^2+y^2$:
$$8\sin^2 s\geq 8\cos^2 s\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{\pi}{4}\leq s\leq\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Then you can apply the formula.